# Error when Reinstalling or Uninstalling Extension from Magento Connect Manager?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento1.9.3

I am using Magento 1.9.3.6. When I'm trying to reinstall or uninstall an extension from Magento Connect Manager. It is showing this error 
[image]

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.
Thank You

Comment: It occurs because of cookie not is correctly set or .htacces is wrong or folder permission may cause this problem.

Comment: @RamaChandranM - i have checked that it is not cookie related issue. I explain in details in another question what's actually happening . if you  know how to resolve these issue. kindly help me. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204172/magento-channel-community-edition-is-not-showing-in-magento-connect-manager

Comment: Sure i will check and try to provide solution