# Magento Channel Community Edition is not showing in Magento Connect Manager?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento1.9.3

I am using Magento 1.9.3.6. In Magento Connect Manager, installed modules are showing in two parts

1. In first part all installed modules are working perfectly. No issue in reinstalling or uninstalling and Magento Channel is showing Community Edition

[image]

2. In the second part of installed modules there are issues in reinstalling or uninstalling and Magento channel is not community Edition

[image]

3. When I am trying to reinstall or uninstall the second part of any modules, error is showing

> no actions selected

[image]

Kindly help me to resolve this issue

Thank You